# Get WordPress Custom Post Type Excerpt to appear in RESt API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Does anyone know how to get the excerpt of a custom post type to appear in the WordPress REST API?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you've managed to solve this issue by now but for anyone who stumbles across this post in seek of help (as I did), the following worked for me:

```
add_filter("rest_prepare_{$post_type}", function ($response) {
    $response->data['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
    return $response;
});
```

Links:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-post_type/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Comment: Thank you for this!  Making a custom post type and simply adding support for the excerpt is not enough to have it load in the WP REST API.  You must register these as you have eloquently pointed out.  You are my savior today!

Answer (score 0):

You can get excerpt in REST API response like below, This is the default excerpt of post,

Example response JSON data,

```
"excerpt":{  
         "rendered":"<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!<\/p>\n",
         "protected":false
      },
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I know where to find it in the JSON response. My question is how do I get the except from a CPT to appear in the JSON object.

Comment: Rfer this may be helps you,https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/

Comment: Thanks, I have already read through the docs and do not see a clear way of adding the excerpt